# Upgraded at counter - not receiving Krisflyer miles?

Tags: bookings, loyalty-programs, singapore-airlines, upgrades

I upgraded one of my legs on a flight from economy class to business class at the counter for Singapore Airlines (and paid ~$1200 USD for that). I'm trying to go back to claim missing miles, but they are telling me that since it was a "last minute upgrade" that I am not eligible for business class miles.

This seems shady...can anyone help me confirm that this is true?

Comment: Was this a [mySQupgrade](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/plan-travel/yourbooking/mysqupgrade/) offer you accepted? If that's the case, "any accrual of KrisFlyer miles, Elite miles, PPS Value, or miles from other KrisFlyer partner airlines will be based on your original booking." It's not uncommon for these "discounted" upgrades at check-in time to carry different terms and conditions, but it would depend exactly on what kind of upgrade you purchased.

Comment: Good question. I actually booked the upgrade because I was going to miss my original flight and had to change it to a later one which only had biz class availability.